# Is there a way I can list all these directory files in once?

Tags: python

I want to list all the files that in this specific directories in once.

**Desktop Files, Documents Files, Downloads Files, and Pictures Files.**

```
import os

os.listdir(path)
```

I want to try like this, list two directories in once.

```
import os

os.listdir(desktop_path + downloads_path)

# output will be desktop files and downloads files together.
```

Is there I can perform this with `os.listdir` ?

---

**Edit:**

I want my program to print like this:

```
myFile.txt
txtfile.jpg
```

Okay, I have this but it prints me the files in a list, how can I unpack the list like I want ?

```
import os

desktopPath = os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE'], 'Desktop')
DownloadsPath = os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE'], 'Downloads')

paths = [desktopPath, DownloadsPath]

for i in paths:
    print(os.listdir(i))
```

Comment: what exactly you want list  ,os.listdir() will list all the files and directories.

Comment: @VikasSharma I want to list two directories in once.

Comment: you can create list of paths and use for loop to iterate on  each path

Comment: @VikasSharma os.listdir() can't hold a list, I tried to convert it to str but it still not working.

Comment: @VikasSharma No matter, it working. I will post answer soon.

Comment: @VikasSharma Please see my edit, I don't know how to unpack the list

Comment: please check my answer it will print in the format you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os

desktopPath = os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE'], 'Desktop')
DownloadsPath = os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE'], 'Downloads')

paths = [desktopPath, DownloadsPath]

for i in paths:
    for file in os.listdir(i):
        print(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

os.listdir() will list everything in that directory. But it seems like you only want files so you could try.

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
```

you could also use glob

```
import glob
print(glob.glob("/desktop"))
```

Comment: This is not what I want, I want to list two directories in once.